# How to get OneHotEncoding labels in ML.NET

Tags: ml.net

Encoding category column into one-hot encoding vector is a simple task.

However, I don't know how to get one-hot encoding labels from the presented code since it is important in order to know which encoding column represents a category label.

So the following code encodes the category column into one-hot encoding vector.

```cs
//create dataview from the string array 'colVector'
IDataView data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<IrisFlower>(colVector);

//create a pipeline to transform the category into one-hot encoding vector 
var fitData = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(nameof(IrisFlower.Label)).Fit(data);
var transData = fitData.Transform(data);
var convertedData = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<EncodedIrisFlower>(transData, true);
```

So, my question is how to get category labels (`sentosa`,`virginica`,,`versicolor`) from the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is a method called `GetSlotNames`. This will give you a `VBuffer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>>`, where each string in the buffer is the label for the corresponding index into the `OneHotEncoding` vector.

```cs
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

    IrisFlower[] colVector = new IrisFlower[]
    {
        new IrisFlower() { Label = "a" },
        new IrisFlower() { Label = "b" },
        new IrisFlower() { Label = "c" }
    };

    IDataView data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<IrisFlower>(colVector);

    var fitData = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(nameof(IrisFlower.Label)).Fit(data);
    var transData = fitData.Transform(data);
    var convertedData = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<EncodedIrisFlower>(transData, true);

    VBuffer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> labels = default;
    transData.Schema["Label"].GetSlotNames(ref labels);
    foreach (var label in labels.DenseValues())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(label);
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetColumn` method should help you do that.

Similar to the pipeline you have, I have the below. I did add the label field in the `IrisData` class.

```
var data = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile<IrisData>("./iris.data", hasHeader: false, separatorChar: ',');

var shuffledData = context.Data.ShuffleRows(data);

var transData = context.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("LabelOneHot", nameof(IrisData.Label))
    .Fit(shuffledData)
    .Transform(shuffledData);
```

From there we can extract the column values.

```
var oneHotLabels = transData.GetColumn<float[]>("LabelOneHot").ToArray();
var originalLabels = transData.GetColumn<string>("Label").ToArray();
```

With the `Label` column, just get an array of the distinct items.

```
var labels = originalLabels.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Then they can be looped through to determine the correct label based off the one hot encoding.

```
foreach (var item in oneHotLabels)
{
    var maxItem = Array.IndexOf(item, item.Max());

    Console.WriteLine(labels[maxItem]);
}
```

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is an approach to get those values from the data directly. However, if the data are shuffled during the transformation, the order of the category labels could be changed.
So, the ``LabelOneHot`` column has information about the category labels and their order. The information is stored in the annotation of the column, but I cannot retrieve that information through the code.  

I think it is safer to get that information from the transformed column itself rather than from the original data.

Comment: Since I get the column from the transformed data, it still works even if the data is shuffled. I updated the answer to reflect this.